# How do you make Radio button loop? REACTJS

Tags: css, reactjs, slideshow

I'm using react and want to make a slider using radio buttons make the slider automatic.
Please do answer with an explanation on how to make it automatic. Thank you so much!

JS

```
  setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("page" + slider).defaultChecked = true;
    if (slider < 4) {
      slider ++;
    } else {
      slider + 1;
    }
  }, 1000);
```

Input

````
           <input
            name="control"
            id="page1"
            type="radio"
            defaultChecked
          />
          <input
            name="control"
            id="page2"
            type="radio"

          />
          <input
            name="control"
            id="page3"
            type="radio"

          />
          <input
            name="control"
            id="page4"
            type="radio"
  
          />```
````

Comment: What do you mean by 'automatic'?

Comment: I mean buy making a checked button switch to another radio button automatically. (bad english I know) kinda like autoplay for image sliders